# Issue building Nuxt3 project after release

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I was developing a site on Nuxt 3, I am maintaining it, it so happened that my operating system was reinstalled and after installing all the dependencies, I can no longer build and upload the site, getting this error.

> [nuxt] [request error] globalThis.__publicAssetsURL is not a function

```
 7: 00007FF73CAA6344 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+4244
 8: 00007FF73CAA3CC0 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+2000
 9: 00007FF73CAC19D0 v8::internal::FreeListManyCached::Reset+1408
10: 00007FF73CAC2085 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw+37
11: 00007FF73CAD775B v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewRawOneByteString+75
12: 00007FF73C8BAFDB v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten+395
13: 00007FF73C62523B v8::internal::WasmTableObject::Fill+603
14: 00007FF73C80D179 v8::internal::RegExp::ExperimentalOneshotExec+1161
15: 00007FF73C80CC37 v8::internal::RegExp::Exec+199
16: 00007FF73C7E8AEC v8::internal::DeclarationScope::was_lazily_parsed+21452
17: 00007FF73CCA9571 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+494417
18: 00007FF73CD00963 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+851779
19: 00007FF73CC9D0F4 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+444116
20: 0000015876047A0B
```

---

I tried:

- I completely reinstalled the project
- changed `package.json`, lock.json and node_modules
- tried to run it from different computers and different operating systems.

All I can say is that the problem started after Nuxt 3 was released.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JY2Z.png)

Comment: What is your Node.js version? From which version to which are you migrating (like Nuxt `RC13` towards `3.0`)? Maybe checking the various [changelogs here](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/releases) may have something related to your issue. I bumped [this question](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/6784#discussioncomment-4235431) on Github. Otherwise, it's probably coming from some of your code. If nothing was updated on your side, then it's probably a breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

i already faced this issue and what i believe Probably you have `Nuxt 3.0.0-rc.11` version. It can work with NITRO version `0.5.4`. you can check all the detail with this command i.e. `npx nuxi info` if found similar version which i have mentioned so you should install `nitro 0.5.4` using command like:

###### 1. verify nuxt Infomation:

`npx nuxi info`

###### 2. Install Nitro specific version:

`npm i nitro@0.5.4`

Comment: The version is indeed higher, after installing via npm i nitro@0.5.4 and trying to deploy, the error remained the same

Comment: I tried to try again and as it turned out, he can not install this version, the screen attached by editing the question

Comment: @АлексейОгневой try to remove nitro version first in case ~ npm i nitro@0.5.4 ~ not working. you should also delete you package-lock.json or yarn.lock and then reinstall the nitro version

Comment: i removed node_modules, package-json and lock, before installing all dependencies i tried to install nitro first but same error

Comment: what is you node version?

Comment: Node Version:     `v16.14.1`

Comment: @АлексейОгневой mine version is 16.17.1 please upgrade your version may be it help you

Comment: At random, "nuxt" helped: "^3.0.0-rc.8". Thank you